# Rails 4 - Application.js contains merge conflicts, not sure how to resolve them

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, git, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I have a Rails app in which my `Application.js` generated by sprocket somehow got merge conflicts - and I'm not sure how to remove them. In Chrome I get the the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <<
```

And I can see that this is included in the file:

```
[...]
<<<<<<< HEAD

//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require chosen-jquery
=======
>>>>>>> 9e6c961b13c6c09da1cb8cdc055c799b829ff824
//= require jquery.purr
[...]
```

But I currently can't see any merge conflicts in my own `Application.js` file (not the generated one).

I have tried both `rake assets:clean`, `rake assets:precompile` and `rake assets:clobber` without any success.

Any ideas on how I can get rid of these errors?

**Update for clarification**

This is how my manual (not generated by Sprockets) `application.js` file looks like:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require scaffold
//= require jquery.purr
//= require best_in_place
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require jquery-fileupload
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require jquery-ui
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery.countdown
//= require autocomplete-rails
//= require bootstrapValidator.min

//= require turbolinks

//= require_tree .
```

So, no merge conflicts in this file, but rather in the file that gets generated by the sprockets gem.

Can also mention that I recently had a merge conflict in my "manual" `application.js` file, but the error / conflict persists for some reason in the file that was generated by sprockets - and I'm not sure how to remove it.

Comment: `<<< HEAD` and `>>> mumbojumbo` are output of a `diff`command and should not exist within a file... How have you created `Application.js`? It should only contain valid javascript and sprockets, nothing more (and comments, of course)

Comment: @RubyRacer I added some clarification to my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting my local repository / folder and then cloning my remote repository made it work. Probably some caching issue. Might be a better way to get it working though, but I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 0):

The merge conflicts originally solves manually. Just make sure that application.js looks good before doing `git add app/assets/javascripts/application.js && git commit`

I believe that your `application.js` file should looks like this:

```
[...]
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require jquery.purr
[...]
```

Comment: Thanks, I've update `application.js` as you suggested. Still seeing the `merge conflicts` in the generated file for some reason though.